# Flow type refinement to non-nullable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, static-analysis, flowtype

Somewhere in my Flow annotated JavaScript code I have an object `obj` defined with **nullable** field `field`.

```
let obj: { field: ?number } = { field: 1 };
```

I have a function `func` that accepts argument `arg` which has the same structure as `obj` **but** `field` should be **non-nullable** at this time.

```
function func(arg: {field: number}){
    // do something
}
```

I'm calling the `func` with `obj` after checking that the `obj.field` is not `null` or `undefined`, hoping that Flow will do it's **type refining** magic and understand that `obj.field` is always `number` and it's type is OK to pass to the `func`.

```
if(obj.field !== null && obj.field !== undefined){
    func(obj);
}
```

Surprisingly getting an error, Flow doesn't like it:

```
14:   func(obj);
           ^ Cannot call `func` with `obj` bound to `arg` because null or undefined [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `field`.
References:
4:   field: ?number            ^ [1]
9: function func(arg: {field: number}){
                              ^ [2]
```

[Run online in the Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjoFMAupYCMBWAuUAb0VFEgEtVoATQgfgDsBXAW21QCdEBfUAXmKlyVWoQCMvANzIKkABQ5cAOkrUaoAIT9BLaNFAAyQ1jyrRG7YOaMaqSo1Q0AlCQCQkGwGNFeZzJ5kT0YvdApYRnJveQBDTgBzQiI1MVAWdi4eV0Q3EFAaWFAAZ1hWDAALCkZ43kQgA)

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. What is best practice to make it work?

The code snippets above are simplified version of the code to demonstrate the problem. Actual `obj` is more complex.

Comment: The type is static; the type checking doesn't pay attention to the fact that the reference to the object is inside that "guard" `if` statement. That test will work at runtime but the type checker doesn't know that. All it knows is that you're passing an object whose "field" value *can* be `null` to a function where it *can't*.

Answer (score 2):

First-off, Flow's refinement applies to individual fields here, but generally you aren't refining the whole object's type, so you can't refine an object's type based on refinement of a single field (as far as I'm aware). Even if you could, this example would still not be typesafe. Here's something that illustrates the problem with allowing this:

```
let obj: { field: ?number } = { field: 1 };

if(obj.field !== null && obj.field !== undefined){
    func(obj);

    obj.field = null;
}

function func(arg: {field: number}){
    setTimeout(() => {
      var value: number = arg.field;
    }, 10);
}
```

Given purely the restrictions you're looking for, this would typecheck, but the `value` inside the `func` timeout callback would actually be `null`.

The only way your given code could be safe with typechecking is if the `arg.field` value were marked contravariant (note the `-` in the property name for `func` now, e.g.

```
let obj: { field: ?number } = { field: 1 };

if(obj.field !== null && obj.field !== undefined){
    func(obj);
}

function func(arg: {-field: number}){
  arg.field = 43;
}
```

([On Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjoFMAupYCMBWAuUAb1EgEtVoATQgfgDsBXAW21QCdQBfUAXmNIVqhAIzcA3MjKQAFDlwA6cpSqgAhL35No0UADI9WPEqGqN-RvSqpy9VFQCURRAEhIlgMZy8DyV2Tu9B7oZLD0pJ4yAIbsAOaERAC0ysKgTKwcXE6IoKAxsSYqfKAALADMfohAA))

This effectively would make `arg.field` write-only, which is fine because *writing* a number to `field` would always be safe, but *reading* one is not safe in the long term.

> What is best practice to make it work?

It depends on what your real code does, to some extent. In this specific example I'd say pass the number directly as the argument, but assuming it needs to be an object, you could consider creating a new object with just the properties `func` needs.